# Retrieve text from element to use in textbox

Tags: html, vb.net

I am making a program that checks a users worth by using a website which returns information on said user. I would like to use some of that information on my program. I hoped reading the page out and trimming the returned string would work but the information I am after was not in there. Below is my most recent attempt to do so which returns nothing at all.

```
Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long, strAccount As String
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://rbx.trade/s/" + TextBox2.Text)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim datastream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(datastream)
    Dim strData As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    pos1 = InStr(strData, "rap")
    pos1 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, "rap", vbTextCompare)
    pos2 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, "rank", vbTextCompare)
    strAccount = strData.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1)
    textbox5.text = strAccount
```

A view of what I want to get:

[image]

I am trying to return the RAP value to textbox5 on this user it is 1,104
I have been trying for so long and can not figure this out for the life of me. Someone please help.

Comment: Parse the HTML using a HTML parser (such as HtmlAgilityPack) instead. It will be much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do things like this ..

```
'cold
pos1 = strdata.IndexOf("class=""rap"">") + "class=""rap"">".length
strdata = strdata.remove(0,pos1)

'warm
pos1 = strdata.IndexOf("hide-on-small-only"">") + "hide-on-samll-only"">".length
strdata = strdata.remove(0,pos1)

'hot
dim result as string = strdata.remove(strdata.indexof("<",0))
```

Comment: I get a "comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected" error  on on the 'warm section, the + "hide-

Comment: sorry I should have used two double quotes not three, now corrected

Comment: returns the following:

Comment: &copy;2017 Rights reserved to ROBLOX Corp.